# How to integrate NicEdit rich text editor with asp.net C# (.aspx) pages

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I found many solution for Text editing in web pages, But one of most handy and light weight Text Editor is [NiEditor](http://nicedit.com/) . I was burning my head to upload image by editor to my own server. By default editor uploads images on [IMGUR] server.
My question is how to upload image(s) to my own server instead of IMGUR server? [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWBEB.png)

Comment: NicEdit documentation page would be a nice place to start reading before asking questions on SO... so, take a look at [NicEdit wiki](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options)

Comment: I go through NicEdit wiki before asking question. There is nice description about configuration of NiceEdit, but all description is about PHP only. I searched a day for solution in asp .net but no solution i found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I found nice solution for image uploading in .net. Generic Handlers are the best option for image uploading.
Please follow the steps below to integrate NicEditor with asp.net using C#.

1. Download latest nicEdit.js from nicedit.com.
2. Modify line no 1888 with the below code

```js
 nicURI: "images.ashx"
```

3. Create a generic handler to upload image named images.ashx.
4. Write the below code in yourhandler.ashx file inside public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) .

   ```
   string baseImageLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Admin/imgs/");

   HttpPostedFile Files;
   Files = context.Request.Files[0]; // Load File collection into HttpFileCollection variable.
   //Files.ContentLength;
   //Files.ContentType;
   if (Files != null && Files.ContentLength > 0)
   {
       System.IO.Stream fileStream = Files.InputStream;
       fileStream.Position = 0;

       byte[] fileContents = new byte[Files.ContentLength];
       fileStream.Read(fileContents, 0, Files.ContentLength);
       string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Files.FileName).ToLower();
       string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Files.FileName);
       System.Drawing.Image image = null;
       if (fileName != null)
       {
           if (fileExt == ".jpg" || fileExt == ".gif" || fileExt == ".jpg" || fileExt == ".png" || fileExt == ".jpeg")
           {
               image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(fileContents));
               if (System.IO.File.Exists(baseImageLocation + "/" + fileName))
                   fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + fileExt;
               Files.SaveAs(baseImageLocation + fileName);
           }
       }
       string link = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Admin/imgs/") + fileName;

       string imageHeight = image.Height.ToString();
       string imageWidth = image.Width.ToString();
       string json = "";


       json += "{" +
               "\"links\": \"" + link + "\"," +
               "\"width\": \"" + imageWidth + "\"," +
               "\"height\": \"" + imageHeight + "\"" +
               "}";


       context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
       context.Response.Write(json);

   }
   ```
5. Please be noted , place your nicEdit.js file and yourhandler.ashx file in the same folder so that it can be easily  accessed path of the handler.
6. Create image folder to upload images (uploaded by editor) in solution directory.

Comment: hi. I used your code to save image in local server. It's working  fine. But I'm not able to show the uploaded image into the textarea. Do you have idea? Can you help me please?

Comment: Hi.. Just save all the text of  text area in file or database and to display get the stored text into textbox and set text property of text area(in case of reach text editor set value of text area.)